# Save an image in imageview to the internal memory

Tags: xamarin.android

I read the code and convert it to a barcode and put the barcode as an image inside
imageview.

Next step, I want to save the image from the imageview in the internal memory.

I tried and it didn't work.

```
  Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.Drawable).Bitmap;

              if (bmp != null)
              {
                  byte[] reducedImage = btarry.GetImageStreamAsBytes(bmp);

                  var filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).ToString(), "NewFolder");

                  if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(filename))
                  {
                      System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filename);
                  }

                  filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff"), "qrcode.jpg");
                  using (var fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filename))
                  {
                      await fileOutputStream.WriteAsync(reducedImage);
                  }

                  if (bmp != null)
                  {
                      bmp.Recycle();
                      bmp = null;
                  }
                 
              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you can use the bmp.Compress() to save it not the stream and byte arraylist. In addition, ExternalStorageDirectory returns the root path of your external storage and will be deprecated in API 29. Finally, you used the Path.Combine twice and the second time will replace the first time. You can use the following code to save the image and it will create a folder named with the time.

```
 Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)imageview.Drawable).Bitmap;
             if (bmp != null)
             {
                 
                 var filename1 = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")).AbsolutePath;
                 var filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(filename1,  "qrcode.jpg");
                 using (System.IO.FileStream os = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
                 {
                     bmp.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, os);
                     os.Close();
                 }
                 if (bmp != null)
                 {
                     bmp.Recycle();
                     bmp = null;
                 }

             }
```